# Running Visual Studio 2008 on windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8

The company I work at is considering upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8. We are using Visual Studio 2008 and we are hoping to continue using it on Windows 8. I was wondering if anyone is running Visual Studio on Windows 8 and if you are how has it been working out for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why no upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I managed to use Visual 2008 on Windows 8 for building Win32 with no problem. It's not my main environment but it works as expected. It is possible to have VS2008, 2010 and 2012 on the same machine: you need to install the oldest version of Visual Studio first.

That's not to say that all other SDKs will install fine on Windows 8, but I suspect most will work.

Comment: Just to reiterate for emphasis, but if installing multiple versions of Visual Studio on the same machine, they **MUST BE INSTALLED FROM OLDEST TO NEWEST!**